# Difference between GridFS.put() and GridFSBucket.upload_from_stream()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

In the [doc](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs/index.html#module-gridfs), it says:

```
GridFS.put()
```

> Put data in GridFS as a new file.

and

```
GridFSBucket.upload_from_stream()
```

> Uploads a user file to a GridFS bucket.
>
> Reads the contents of the user file from source and uploads it to the
>   file filename.

I figured one is storing a file in `GridFS` and the other in a `GridFSBucket`.
But what does this even mean? When to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this thread](http://mongodb.2344371.n4.nabble.com/Pymongo-GridFS-vs-GridFSBucket-td22221.html):

`GridFSBucket` is an addition to the GridFS API needed to unify the Mongo APIs across various drivers.

It is a newer API and a more aligned one so it should be preferred over `GridFS` class (also for the flexibility reasons). The older API of `GridFS` is not going away but there is a higher chance of this happening in the unforeseeable future.

Under the cover `GridFSBucket` exposes a few more options (e.g. possibility for more than one file bucket - not only `'fs'` one).